# IntilliJ IDEA loses the classpath of my dependacies

Tags: java, spring, jsp, intellij-idea

It seems that my Intellij IDEA has gone crazy, it finds some of the tag libs I use and not the others.

It cannot find spring taglib and jsp/jstl/core, They are both in the dependencies and they are both used in the compilation, my applications works great, it is just that the Editor cannot find them, so no code completion.

It can find jsp/jstl/fmt and some other tag libs with no problem, but not the spring or the jsp/jstl/core ones.

tried removing the dependencies from the local repo and getting them again, but still no use.

only thing that worked before when this happened was to remove and reinstall IntelliJ, but of course this is very cumbersome, is there any solution to this issue ?

IDEA version is 12.1.5 latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do an invalidate caches
go to File > Invalidate Caches ...

Comment: Yes you are right, it seems that my caches were corrupted some how.

Answer (score 0):

In the maven panel project at the rigth of the intellij editor, select all your maven projects and click at the rigth button mouse. In the contextuel menu shown, click "Reimport".
This will force reimport of maven dependencies.
After than run clean install with maven.

I think that it'll resolve your problem.